# ASP.NET MVC 2 Membership users table mdf file

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-membership, mdf

I have an **MVC 2 project** where I have my own *.mdf file in the App_Data directory. The *.mdf file contains my normal tables but not a users table.

Is it possible to add a Users table to my *.mdf file and work with that instead of the simple register form? (if so: how could this be done?)

Because I don't know how to do these things above, I searched and only found steps to add build in Membership to my mdf file and I tried it:

I tried to add normal build in Membership to my *.mdf file with this:

```
aspnet_regsql.exe -C CONSTRINGHERE -d PATHTOMDFFILEHERE -A all
```

and I changed my Web.config file to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="CompanyDBEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.CompanyDB.csdl|res://*/Models.CompanyDB.ssdl|res://*/Models.CompanyDB.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\CompanyData.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
        <add assembly="System.Data.Entity, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
    </authentication>
    <membership defaultProvider="CompanyDBSqlProvider" userIsOnlineTimeWindow="15">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="CompanyDBSqlProvider"
            type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider"
            connectionStringName="CompanyDBEntities"
            applicationName="/"
            enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
            enablePasswordReset="true"
            requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
            requiresUniqueEmail="true"
            passwordFormat="Hashed"
            maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
            minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
            minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
            passwordAttemptWindow="10"
            passwordStrengthRegularExpression=""
            />

      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider" 
             connectionStringName="CompanyDBEntities" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </profile>
    <roleManager enabled="false">
      <providers>
        <clear />
        <add name="AspNetSqlRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider" 
             connectionStringName="CompanyDBEntities" applicationName="/" />
        <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <pages>
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
        <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
  </system.webServer>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

I did not modify anything else. I did not change the AccountController or something.
I builded and ran my MVC 2 application and went to LogOn and registered an account but got stuck there:

```
Account creation was unsuccessful. Please correct the errors and try again.

    * The password retrieval answer provided is invalid. Please check the value and try again.
```

**Summary:**

I thought that it would be better to have a Users table in my *.mdf file but I don't know how to do the register/login/logout/membership/etc... things with an own users table.
So I tried adding Membership to my own *.mdf file so that everything would be in that one *.mdf file but that gives me also problems.

Maybe this info is important:
In the future I want it to be possible to let users register and login via Hotmail, Gmail, OpenId and I should need more fields like website, nickname, avatar, etc... other than the basic register form now. Also would need to show a profilepage from the user on the website.

Could anybody help me out?

PS: I don't have experience with Membership in ASP.NET :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered the same problem. You can customize the user register table by doing these:

First of all, configure the sqlmemberprovider service in web.config:

```
  ' add connectionStringName="PhotoSocialMemberService" applicationName="PhotoSocial"
          minRequiredPasswordLength="5" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" 
          requiresQuestionAndAnswer="true"
          name="PhotoSocailMember" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" /'
```

Edit the AccountModel.cs., look for
    the method "CreateUser", the
    abstract class should be like this:

```
  public abstract class MembershipProvider : ProviderBase  
    {...
     public abstract MembershipUser CreateUser(string username, string password, string email, string passwordQuestion, string passwordAnswer, bool isApproved, object providerUserKey, out MembershipCreateStatus status); 
 }
```

in the AccountModel.cs you can find implementation of the abstract method in

```
public interface IMembershipService
{
    int MinPasswordLength { get; }

    bool ValidateUser(string userName, string password);
    MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(string userName, string password, string email, string passwordquestion, string passwordanswer);
    bool ChangePassword(string userName, string oldPassword, string newPassword);
}
```

and in

```
 public MembershipCreateStatus CreateUser(string userName, string password, string email, string passwordquestion, string passwordanswer)  
        {  
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(userName)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "userName");  
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(password)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "password");  
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(email)) throw new ArgumentException("Value cannot be null or empty.", "email");  

            MembershipCreateStatus status;  
            _provider.CreateUser(userName, password, email, passwordquestion, passwordanswer, true, null, out status);  
            return status;  
        }
```

add as many as parameters as you like.

Edit the register model in RegisterModel in AccountModel.cs, add string you want to put into the registerModel:

```
     public class RegisterModel
     {[Required]
                [DisplayName("User name")]
                public string UserName { get; set; }

                [Required]
                [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
                [DisplayName("Email address")]
                public string Email { get; set; }

                [Required]
                [ValidatePasswordLength]
                [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                [DisplayName("Password")]
                public string Password { get; set; }

                [Required]
                [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                [DisplayName("Confirm password")]
                public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }

                [Required]
                [DisplayName("Password security question")]
                public string PasswordQuestion { get; set; }

                [Required]
                [DataType(DataType.Password)]
                [DisplayName("Password security answer")]
                public string PasswordAnswer { get; set; }

            }
```

Last, rewrite the Register.aspx page, add the html tag:

```
Html.LabelFor(m => m.PasswordQuestion)
```

Most important, you need to change the _provider from readonly to private

```
 public class AccountMembershipService : IMembershipService
    {
        private MembershipProvider _provider;
}
```

You can add your validation methods through this progress.